# Ubuntu keeps crashing/freezing, please help!

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, freeze

Been at it for 4 hours trying to get it to work, I looked at numerous complaints about crashes in hopes of solution but nothing worked.

At the login screen, the only thing i can move for the first 10 seconds is the mouse, everything else is frozen and i can't click on any of it. After 10 seconds everything including the mouse freezes and a black screen with text shows up that says

```
GPU lockup - switching to software fbcon
```

After that it continuously says

```
Failed to idle channel 1 
PFIFO - playlist update failed  
Failed to idle channel 2
```

OVER and over again, 5 seconds on the black screen it blinks into the sign in screen for 4 seconds, the goes back and throws the messages above at me.

I have tried installing priority drivers
I have tried numerous things with coding, nothing has worked

More information: i have GTX 580 installed, 8 GB of RAM, 64 bit version.
I got ubuntu started but I was never able to enter through the login.
So I have to use the CD install and set `nomodeset` or `acpi=off`.

I have tried numerous things with the terminal, trying to install the graphics drivers manually.

Everything i do seems to reset when i reboot, as if it never happend. So all in all, proprietary drivers never take effect because they reset on reboot no matter what i try to do.

Comment: Have you tried installing an alternate desktop manager, ie: kdm, gdm? This could help rule out lightdm as the cause?

Comment: I dont really know how im supposed to download these
Also, if they change anything in Ubuntu its self then I would rather not use those
I want a base versio

Comment: *"Everything i do seems to reset when i reboot, as if it never happend."* Have you actually installed Ubuntu or are you running from a Live image (CD/USB)?

Comment: A new desktop manager would pretty much just change the software that manages the login screen. To try this press Ctrl+Alt+F2, login, execute 'sudo apt-get install gdm'.

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to the NVIDIA GPU overheating, the GPU slows itself down when overheating and may therefore give you the above symptoms. This can be caused by a cooling problem on your computer. I had a similar issue on a Dell XPS M1530 laptop and had to replace the motherboard, the laptop is now working well. I wrote up some instructions, including my research on the NVIDIA GPU: [Dell XPS M1530 Motherboard Replacement](https://fixitfriends.com/fixits/dell-xps-m1530-motherboard-replacement). Hope that helps.

Comment: Definitely not this, im using a gtx 580 with water cooling